# babel/6to5 - duplicated code when exporting modules

Tags: gulp, amd, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony, babeljs

I'm using Babel to transpile ES6 to ES5 and it works great.
The only problem is that once transpiled each module duplicates these lines:

```
var _get = function get(object, property, receiver) { var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, property); if (desc === undefined) { var parent = Object.getPrototypeOf(object); if (parent === null) { return undefined; } else { return get(parent, property, receiver); } } else if ("value" in desc && desc.writable) { return desc.value; } else { var getter = desc.get; if (getter === undefined) { return undefined; } return getter.call(receiver); } };
var _inherits = function (subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) subClass.__proto__ = superClass; };
var _classCallCheck = function (instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } };
```

As my application is going to have more and more modules defining classes, I cannot imagine waisting so much space just because of these repeated code.

Is there a way to tell Babel to not include them in each module so we can add them only once later ?

I'm using gulp and my config is:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('default', function () {  

    return gulp.src('src/**/*.es6')
        .pipe(babel({ playground: true, experimental: true, modules: 'amd', moduleIds: true }))
        .pipe(concat('tmp/src.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as it is described in the [**documentation**](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/runtime/):

> Babel uses very small helpers for common functions such as `_extend`. By default this will be added to every file that requires it. This duplication is sometimes unnecessary, especially when your application is spread out over multiple files.
>
> This is where the runtime optional transformer comes in. All of the helpers will reference the module `babel-runtime` to avoid duplication across your compiled output.
>
> **Usage**
>
> ```
> require("babel").transform("code", { optional: ["runtime"] });
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> $ babel --optional runtime script.js
> ```

Comment: I'm unclear on this: it seems from the documentation that this option adds all of core-js, which, unless you need core-js, would definitely defeat the benefit of shaving bytes by avoiding helper repetition, right?

Is there no way to not duplicate the helpers without adding core-js?